# Issue with binding platform driver to the platform device

Tags: linux, driver, device-tree

I want to make work mt7622 soc's ethernet controller and faced with this issue. I've compiled `mtk_soc_eth` [driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/mediatek/mtk_eth_soc.c#L3340) as `mkt_eth` [module](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/mediatek/Makefile#L6) and I have an entry in `mt7622-bananapi-bpi-r64.dts` [device tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/boot/dts/mediatek/mt7622-bananapi-bpi-r64.dts) for device, [compatible with driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/boot/dts/mediatek/mt7622.dtsi#L923).

During boot this module is loaded into system automatically (I think after mounting rootfs):

```
[root@nixos:~]# lsmod | grep mtk_eth
mtk_eth                69632  0
dsa_core               98304  1 mtk_eth
```

And it seems registered as platform driver:

```
[root@nixos:~]# ls /sys/bus/platform/drivers/mtk_soc_eth
bind  module  uevent  unbind
```

Also after boot I have an platform device:

```
[root@nixos:~]# ls /sys/bus/platform/devices/1b100000.ethernet
driver_override
modalias
of_node
power
subsystem
supplier:platform:10006000.power-controller
supplier:platform:10209000.apmixedsys
supplier:platform:10210000.topckgen
supplier:platform:10211000.pinctrl
supplier:platform:1b000000.syscon
supplier:platform:1b128000.sgmiisys
uevent
waiting_for_supplier
```

However they are not binded for some reason. Moreover, when I try to bind them manually, I get an error:

```
[root@nixos:~]# echo '1b100000.ethernet' > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/mtk_soc_eth/bind
-bash: echo: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

How can I understand why ethernet device doesn't bind with driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that I figured out where is the problem. It seems that linux kernel have rich debug options) I've enabled dynamic debug to track which happens inside `__driver_probe_device` https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/base/dd.c#L730 function:

```
[root@nixos:~]# echo 'file dd.c +p'>/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
[root@nixos:~]# echo 'file core.c +p'>/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

And then tried to bind device driver and device:

```
[root@nixos:~]# echo '1b100000.ethernet' >/sys/bus/platform/drivers/mtk_soc_eth/bind
-bash: echo: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable
[root@nixos:~]# dmesg -T | tail
...
[Sat Jan  1 00:03:27 2000] bus: 'platform': __driver_probe_device: matched device 1b100000.ethernet with driver mtk_soc_eth
[Sat Jan  1 00:03:27 2000] platform 1b100000.ethernet: error -EPROBE_DEFER: supplier 1b000000.syscon not ready
```

It seems that one of the dependent devices (`1b000000.syscon`) is not ready (at the same time `/sys/bus/platform/devices/1b100000.ethernet/waiting_for_supplier` was still `0` for some reason). I need to load `clk-mt7622-eth` driver as well.